# How to set the default value of a option in a theme?

Tags: theme-development, theme-options, array

```
$shortname = "nuod";

array( "name" => "Custom Logo URL",
    "desc" => "Enter the link to your site's custom logo.",
    "id" => $shortname."_logo",
    "type" => "text",
    "std" => "newlogo.png")
```

How do i make the std be automatically set as the value for `<?php echo get_option('nuod_logo'); ?>`

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28456/how-to-save-uploaded-image-in-custom-option-panel/28472#28472

Answer (score 4):

As @Ashfame as already pointed out, you shouldn't store defaults in the database - that should be for user selected options (of course, if they select the defaults, then fine - store them :).

However, you don't need to use `wp_parse_args()` either. `get_option` allows you to select a default value. For instance:

```
//If nuod_logo is not found, uses 'newlogo.pnp'
$number = get_option('nuod_logo', 'newlogo.png')
```

However, often themes and plug-ins (as they should) keep their options in an array which is stored in one row in the database. So

```
$my_plugin_options = get_option('my_plugins_options')
```

is expected to return all options. So you could keep all options in a default array `$my_plugin_defaults`:

```
$my_plugin_options = get_option('my_plugins_options',$my_plugin_defaults)
```

but this isn't great either - you have to redeclare `$my_plugin_defaults` which is simply duplicating code, making room for bugs, ugly - or you make it a global variable which is just plain wrong. The solution is to create your own '`get_option`' which builds on WordPress' settings API:

```
 function wpse28954_get_option( $option_name='' ){

      $defaults = array(
          // Array of defaults: option => default value 
      )
      $options = get_option('my_plugins_options',$defaults);

      //Parse defaults again - see comments
      $options = wp_parse_args( $options, $defaults );

      if( !isset($options[$option_name]) )
           return false;

      return $options[$option_name];

 }
```

*This could be improved by allow `wpse28954_get_option` to set a default value in case its not in the defined defaults*

Now your defaults are stored in one, easy to manage place and you can use `wpse28954_get_option['my-option']` to return the saved setting or else the default value.

---

#### Edit

AS **@Ashfame** has pointed out in the comments using `wp_parse_args` has the advantage of providing defaults for an unsaved subset of options. I've updated my answer to include this. (This makes the `$defaults` in `get_option` rather redundant). +1 for **@Ashfame**'s solution which was first to suggest using `wp_parse_args`.

Comment: IMO, `wp_parse_args()` is still better because in using the default parameter of `get_option()`, that kicks in only when `get_option()` doesn't return anything from database. It won't be useful in the case when you have a subset of options filled in and wants to fill the missing ones from the defaults, like when you are upgrading your plugin, and all existing users of that plugin doesn't have the newly added setting in their database yet. We would want the default to kick in for that.

Comment: Very good point! I've updated my answer to include this. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is important which most of the people don't get right. Don't save the defaults in the database. You should be using `wp_parse_args()` for this purpose.

```
$defaults = array (
    'logo' => 'http://domain.com/logo.png',
    'do_extra_thing' => false
);

// Parse incomming $args into an array and merge it with $defaults
$options = wp_parse_args( $options, $defaults );
```

When `$options` is empty, like you have just installed a plugin, it can work off without writing anything in your database. And when it has some values inside it, the missing ones will come from `$defaults` array.