# Passing array in add_option()

Tags: php, theme-development, themes, theme-customizer, options

I have to create a option page in my custom theme wordpress. here is is a sample of code

```
<?php

    function bguru_register_settings(){

   $default_options=array(
        'bguru_logo'=>'http://templategraphy.com/demo/businessguru/images/logo.png',
        'bguru_vimeo'=>'',
        'bguru_skype'=>'',
        'bguru_dribbble'=>'',
        'bguru_slide_one_image'=>'',
        'bguru_slide_one_heading'=>'',
        'bguru_slide_one_text'=>''
         );

        add_option('bguru_options',$default_options);

        register_setting('tgbusinessguru', 'bguru_options');
    }

    add_action('admin_init', 'bguru_register_settings');

    function bguru_register_options_page(){

    add_theme_page('Business Guru Options', 'Theme Customizer', 'edit_theme_options', 'bguru-options', 'bguru_options_page');

}

    add_action('admin_menu', 'bguru_register_options_page');

    function bguru_options_page(){
        $options=get_option('bguru_options');

        ?>
<div class="wrap">
    <?php
 screen_icon(); ?>
    <h1>Business Guru Options</h1>
    <form method="post" action="options.php"> 
        <?php
 settings_fields('tgbusinessguru'); ?>
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th><h2>General</h2><th>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">

                    <th scope="row"><label for="bguru_logo">Logo:</label></th>

                    <td><input type="text" id="bguru_logo" size="50" name="bguru_options[bguru_logo]" value="<?php echo $options['bguru_logo']; ?>" /></td>

                </tr>

                <tr valign="top">
                    <th><h2>Social Links</h2><th>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row"><label for="bguru_vimeo">Vimeo:</label></th>
                    <td><input type="text" id="bguru_vimeo" size="50" name="bguru_options[bguru_vimeo]" value="<?php echo $options['bguru_vimeo']; ?>" /></td>

                 </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row"><label for="bguru_skype">Skype:</label></th>
                    <td><input type="text" id="bguru_skype" size="50" name="bguru_options[bguru_skype]" value="<?php echo $options['bguru_skype']; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row"><label for="bguru_dribbble">Dribbble:</label></th>
                    <td><input type="text" id="bguru_dribbble" size="50" name="bguru_options[bguru_dribbble]" value="<?php echo $options['bguru_dribbble']; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">

                    <th scope="row"><label for="bguru_slide_one_image">Image:</label></th>

                    <td><input type="text" id="bguru_slide_one_image" size="50" name="bguru_options[bguru_slide_one_image]" value="<?php
 echo $options['bguru_slide_one_image']; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row"><label for="bguru_slide_one_heading">Heading:</label></th>
                    <td><input type="text" id="bguru_slide_one_heading" size="50" name="bguru_options[bguru_slide_one_heading]" value="<?php
 echo $options['bguru_slide_one_heading']; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row"><label for="bguru_slide_one_text">Description:</label></th>
                    <td><textarea type="text" id="bguru_slide_one_text" style="width:439px;height:100px;" name="bguru_options[bguru_slide_one_text]"><?php  echo $options['bguru_slide_one_text']; ?></textarea></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
          <?php submit_button(); ?>
       </form>
     </div>
<?php  } ?>
```

All the form details are passed by dashboard I want if admin forget to fill the logo field then by default this $default_options work so by default logo field fill up but when I try to access the array using get_option I'm not getting the results I expect.

Comment: Please suggest some solution what i am doing wrong your suggestions really help me

Comment: I edit my code please do check my edited code and suggest some solutions

Answer (score 4):

I think that you have added `bguru_options` option before. If `bguru_options` already exists, `add_option()` does nothing. To modify the value of existing options you should use `update_option()` instead.

**EDIT**

I confirm what I thought. You are running `add_option('bguru_options', $default_options);` in every `admin_init`. `bguru_options` option was added to database in the first run and subsequent calls to `add_option('bguru_options', $default_options);` are doing nothing.

- Use `update_option()` to change the value of a existent option. If the option doesn't exist, it will be created.
- Use `add_option()` if you really need it. For example, if you need to set `autoload=no`. This parameter is not accepted by `update_option()`. Do this preferably during plugin/theme activation
- If you need to use `add_option()` and you are not sure if the option already exists, use `delete_option()` before call `add_option()`.

**EDIT 2**

I've tested your code exactly as it is and I've tested it. The default logo URL is correctly added to database in the `bguru_options` option and returned by `get_option('bguru_options');`:

```
$options=get_option('bguru_options');
var_dump($options['bguru_logo']);
```

There is no problem at all. The only drawback is that if the you leave the URL field empty, the default logo URL is not set because, I repeat, `add_option()` is doing nothing in subsequent calls because `bguru_options` option already exists.

I've tested the code and it works. If it does not work for you I will need more information. Maybe some debug log?

Anyway, I wnat to show you how `get_option()` support default values without the need of [store default values in the database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28954/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-a-option-in-a-theme):

```
$default_options=array(
     'bguru_logo'=>'http://templategraphy.com/demo/businessguru/images/logo.png',
     'bguru_vimeo'=>'',
     'bguru_skype'=>'',
     'bguru_dribbble'=>'',
     'bguru_slide_one_image'=>'',
     'bguru_slide_one_heading'=>'',
     'bguru_slide_one_text'=>''
 );
 $bguru_options = get_option('bguru_options', $bguru_options_defaults);
 //Set defaults for unsaved subset in the array
 $bguru_options = wp_parse_args( $bguru_options, $bguru_options_defaults );
```

Comment: Thanks @cybmeta for reply no i am not added any bguru_option before i also used update_option() but the issue remain the same.please suggest some solution..

Comment: Where/When are you executing `bguru_register_settings()`?

Comment: Again thanks @cybmeta for your reply below register_setting() check my updated code

Comment: I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks you so much @cybmeta for your reply i am not sure bguru_option already exits or not so i used delete_option() before add_option() as you said `delete_option('bguru_options');`
`add_option('bguru_options',$default_options);` still the problem remain the same.

Comment: i edited my code please see my code and suggest some solutions.

Comment: I've teste your code as it is and it works. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks @ cybmeta for your reply and sorry for the late reply i am doing the same as you said still by default logo image is not come and error_log file show zero errors. please suggest some solutions and again thanks for suggestions.

Comment: As I said, I tested your code and it works. If it not work for you it is because other code, plugin or theme you are using that conflict with the code. Anyway, you should forget the idea of store default options in database and use the default parameter of `get_option`, which is the correct way to use default values in Wordpres options API. Please, refer to the code and links posted in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You should encode the array to json or serialize it before adding it as an option:

```
  add_option('bguru_options',json_encode($default_options));
```

or

```
  add_option('bguru_options',serialize($default_options));
```

Comment: Thanks @lucian for your reply i am doing the same as you said  but my problem remain the same..

Comment: You do not need to serialize values. If the value needs to be serialized, then it will be serialized before it is inserted into the database. Remember, resources cannot be serialized or added as an option. - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/